# ReportConsumable is missing in Store of Windows 8.0 SDK

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

In MSDN official document i found:

***Important**  Failure to report fulfilled consumables to the Windows Store will result in the user being unable to purchase that product again until fulfillment for the previous purchase is reported.*

But in Windows 8.0 SDK function **ReportConsumableFulfillmentAsync** is missing, i just using **RequestProductPurchaseAsync** and that's all.

When i submit my App to the Windows Store with 8.0 SDK, will is correctly working my consumable In-App Purchases ?

Answer (score 0):

Per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.store.currentapp.reportconsumablefulfillmentasync.aspx **ReportConsumableFulfillmentAsync()** did not exist in the 8.0 SDK.

Is it acceptable for your app to target 8.1 instead of 8.0?

Comment: No, my app must be in 8.0 for support some frameworks